# static Url rewriting in Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I have a codeigniter application in my localserver.
I need some URL rewriting rule for the following.
If any one have any solution please answer.

```
http://localhost/myapp/index.php/users/login
```

to

```
http://localhost/myapp/index.php/usuarios/login
```

How can I do this in Codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

This record in `config/routes.php` will do what you want -

```
$route['users/login'] = 'usuarios/login'; // for login only (static)
$route['users/(:any)'] = 'usuarios/$1'; // for all routes to users (dynamic for functions without parameters)
```

More details here : [URI Routing](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)

Comment: I tried your answer, but its not working the url not changes to http://localhost/myapp/index.php/usuarios/login

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter works like this to access **myFunction** from **Mycontroller** with the value **myVarValue**

```
http://my.webPage.com/index.php/MyController/myFunction/myVarValue
```

U want to alter the URL, yes you can by creating routes on ../application/config/routes.php

```
$route['my-function-(:any)'] = 'MyController/myFunction/$1';
```

**This is the first step**

You created the routes and those are not working?

1. Set the base_url on the file **../application/config/config.php**, in your case will be **http://localhost/myapp**, line number 26 of the file on CI v3.1.6
2. Set the default controller, the default controller that will be inmediatelly accessed by anyone who enters ur website, u set this on **../application/config/routes.php**, your default controller can be the name of a Controller or A function within a controller.

Let's say u have this controller

```
public class MyController extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index(){
        echo 'Hello people, im the index of this controller,'.
             ' im the function u will see everytime u '.
             'access the route http://localhost/myApp/MyController';
    }

    public function notTheIndex(){
         echo 'Hello, im the function u will see if u'.
              'access http://localhost/MyController/notTheIndex';
    }
}
```

Lets say this controller will be ur default controller so as mentioned in the **routes.php file in the line 53 on ci v3.16** set

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'MyController';
//if u want to just access the index method

$route['default_controller'] = 'MyController/notTheIndex';
//if for some reason u have a method u would like to be executed 
//by default as the index page
```

3. Now u want the uris to keep have the names u set

`$route['some-beautiful-name'] = 'MyController/notTheIndex';`

so when u access http://localhost/some-beautiful-name it will show the result of MyController/notTheIndex

Consider that if u are accessing the different pages via a `<a href='some_link'>Some link</a>` and the href values need to be changed to your defined routes, if not, this will still work if they are pointing to controllers, but the uri names will stay the same, lets take the example of 'some.beautiful-name' to access MyController/notTheIndex

**In Your View**

```
<a href="<?=base_url()?>MyController/notTheIndex">This is a link</a>
```

The link will work but the uri name will be http://localhost/MyController/notTheIndex

```
<a href="<?=base_url()?>some-beautiful-name">This is a link</a>
```

The link will work **because u defined a route like this** else it will not and show 404 error, but here the url shown will be http://localhost/some-beautiful-name

Hope my answer helps u.